# How do you convert JSON into a Key Array and Value Array?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to split

```
const alreadyParsed = {"data":[{"name":"foo", "value":"bar"},{"name":"chicken", "value":"nugget"}]}
```

into

```
const headers = ["name","value"]
```

and

```
const datas = [ ["foo","bar"],["chicken","nugget"] ]
```

hopefully, using

```
const headers = alreadyParsed.map(?)
const datas = alreadyParsed.map(?)
```

not sure what I should be googling to figure this out / what options are available.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you know that every data object will have the same keys, you can use `Object.keys()` for your first need, the `headers`.

And for the values (your `datas` variable), you can use the `.map` that you were thinking to use, mixed with `Object.values()`

*(If your keys for `headers` are not always the same, then use the same logic above, used for getting `datas`)*

Below you can see this idea in the working snippet:

```js
const alreadyParsed = {"data":[{"name":"foo", "value":"bar"},{"name":"chicken", "value":"nugget"}]}


const headers  = Object.keys(alreadyParsed.data[0])
const datas  = alreadyParsed.data.map(x => Object.values(x))

console.log(headers)
console.log(datas)
```

Further reading about [Object methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object#Methods).

Comment: That's if we assume that every object in array has the same fields and order

Comment: What is "Object"?  like... a native js function?  I'm looking for terms I can google in hopes of being a strong independent react noob.

edit: yea they do. even if they are null values, they will have every key.

Comment: Object is a data type, like String, Number, Array... You can read more on this [link of documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object), the `Object` have it's prototype with some built-in functions that you can use to create and manipulate objects

Comment: It's not super readable ES6 since I'm trying to keep it in a comment, but this could be inflated to readable and covers any combo of data and keys to zip: `const { headers, data } = alreadyParsed.data.reduce(({ headers, data }, cur) => ({ headers: [ ...new Set([ ...headers, ...(Object.keys(cur))])], data: [ ...data, Object.values(cur) ] }), { headers: [], data: [] })`

Comment: @gelliott181 if you have another alternative to solve Asker's question, post it as answer, not comment in anothers answer. Then if your answer works, even with my answer being the accepted one right now, I would upvote you.

Comment: @CalvinNunes It's not another answer, this is your answer expanded and updated with idiomatic ES6 based on the limitations yours had. If your answer isn't going to work, mine is going to fall flat right behind it. TL;DR this is the change I'd recommend in a code review, but isn't beginner friendly so I didn't edit it in.

Answer (score 0):

This is assuming that all objects in your initial data array are going to have the same keys (name, value).

```
// your initial object
const alreadyParsed = {"data":[{"name":"foo", "value":"bar"},{"name":"chicken", "value":"nugget"}]}

// get the values inside the objects 'data' key
var dataArray = alreadyParsed.data;

// get the objects keys (this is where we assume all index keys are the same as index 0).
var keyArray = Object.keys(this.dataArray[0]);

// build an array of the objects values.
var valuesArray = [];
for (var item of this.dataArray){
   valuesArray.push(Object.values(item);
}

console.log("--Key Array--");
console.log(keyArray );

console.log("--ValueArray--");
console.log(valuesArray );
```

Definitely better off using .map as seen above. :p

Comment: Better to use .map as suggested in @Calvin Nunes answer.